# java client calls python server reports error org.apache.thrift.TApplicationException: Internal error

Tags: java, python, thrift

I use thrift make java server to call python client, the connection is ok
the server response uses 100ms~500ms, and but the error as follows happens about twice in three minutes, can anyone help me ?

python server:

```
transport = TSocket.TServerSocket("127.0.0.1", 8080)
tfactory = TTransport.TBufferedTransportFactory()
pfactory = TBinaryProtocol.TBinaryProtocolFactory()
rpcServer = TServer.TThreadPoolServer(processor, transport, tfactory, pfactory)
```

Java client:

```
socket = new TSocket("127.0.0.1", 8080);        
TProtocol protocol = new TBinaryProtocol(tTransport);
client = new ImDetect.Client(protocol);
```

This is the detail of my error:

> org.apache.thrift.TApplicationException: Internal error   at
>   org.apache.thrift.TApplicationException.read(TApplicationException.java:111)
>     at
>   org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:79)
>     at
>   business.thriftclient.ImDetect$Client.recv_doWatermarkDetect(ImDetect.java:75)
>     at
>   business.thriftclient.ImDetect$Client.doWatermarkDetect(ImDetect.java:62)
>     at
>   business.thriftclient.AsynCThriftClient.imageWatermarkDetection(AsynCThriftClient.java:95)
>     at
>   service.business.soa.ImageWatermarkDetectionServiceImpl.doWatermarkDetection(ImageWatermarkDetectionServiceImpl.java:123)
>     at
>   service.business.soa.ImageWatermarkDetectionServiceImpl.asynImageWatermarkDetection(ImageWatermarkDetectionServiceImpl.java:72)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor107.invoke(Unknown Source)    at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   com.ctriposs.baiji.rpc.server.OperationHandler.invoke(OperationHandler.java:430)
>     at
>   com.ctriposs.baiji.rpc.server.handler.ServiceRequestHandlerBase.executeService(ServiceRequestHandlerBase.java:417)
>     at
>   com.ctriposs.baiji.rpc.server.handler.ServiceRequestHandlerBase.handleInternal(ServiceRequestHandlerBase.java:168)
>     at
>   com.ctriposs.baiji.rpc.server.handler.ServiceRequestHandlerBase.handle(ServiceRequestHandlerBase.java:133)
>     at
>   com.ctriposs.baiji.rpc.server.BaijiServiceHost.processRequest(BaijiServiceHost.java:113)
>     at
>   com.ctriposs.baiji.rpc.server.BaijiServlet.service(BaijiServlet.java:66)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   com.ctriposs.baiji.rpc.client.ribbon.HttpContextFilter.doFilter(HttpContextFilter.java:34)
>     at
>
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)